# Clojure building of URL from constituent parts

Tags: url, clojure

In Python I would do the following:

```
>>> q = urllib.urlencode({"q": "clojure url"})
>>> q
'q=clojure+url'

>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?" + q
>>> url
'http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url'
```

How do I do all the encoding that's done for me above in Clojure? In other words, how do I do something akin to the following:

```
=> (build-url "http://stackoverflow.com/search" {"q" "clojure url"})
"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
user=> (import [java.net URLEncoder])                                                      
java.net.URLEncoder
user=> (str "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" (URLEncoder/encode "clojure url" "UTF-8"))
"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url"
```

I know this is not exactly the same as your Python snippet though. Please see the following post from the Clojure mailing list for a more complete answer:

http://www.mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg29338.html

The code from there will allow you to do this:

```
user=> (encode-params {"q" "clojure url"})
"q=clojure+url"
```

Comment: Noticing the edit, I guess I shouldn't have bothered writing all that... Oh well. +1 for the first complete answer. I still like my `Named`-handling version, so I'm leaving that here. :-)

Answer (score 19):

There is a `url-encode` function in Ring's `ring.util.codec` namespace:

```
(ring.util.codec/url-encode "clojure url")
; => "clojure+url"
```

I'm not sure if there's a prepackaged function to turn a map into a query string, but perhaps this could do the job:

```
(use '[ring.util.codec :only [url-encode]])

(defn make-query-string [m]
  (->> (for [[k v] m]
         (str (url-encode k) "=" (url-encode v)))
       (interpose "&")
       (apply str)))
```

An example:

```
user> (make-query-string {"q" "clojure url" "foo" "bar"})
"q=clojure+url&foo=bar"
```

All that remains is concatenating the result onto the end of a URL:

```
(defn build-url [url-base query-map]
  (str url-base "?" (make-query-string query-map)))
```

Seems to work:

```
user> (build-url "http://stackoverflow.com/search" {"q" "clojure url"})
"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url"
```

---

*Update:*

Perhaps a modified version might make for a more Clojure-friendly experience. Also handles encoding via a Ring-style optional argument with utf-8 as default.

```
(defn make-query-string [m & [encoding]]
  (let [s #(if (instance? clojure.lang.Named %) (name %) %)
        enc (or encoding "UTF-8")]
    (->> (for [[k v] m]
           (str (url-encode (s k) enc)
                "="
                (url-encode (str v) enc)))
         (interpose "&")
         (apply str))))

(defn build-url [url-base query-map & [encoding]]
  (str url-base "?" (make-query-string query-map encoding)))
```

So now we can do

```
user> (build-url "http://example.com/q" {:foo 1})
"http://example.com/q?foo=1"
```

Comment: Ah, almost forgot: `ring.util.codec` also takes an optional encoding argument, defaulting to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 11):

This is the exact REPL equivalent of your python session, using [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http).

```
user=> (require ['clj-http.client :as 'client])
nil
user=> (str "http://stackoverflow.com/search?"
user=*      (client/generate-query-string {"q" "clojure url"}))
"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url"
```

but clj-http makes it even easier:

```
user=> (client/get "http://stackoverflow.com/search?"
user=*             {:query-params {"q" "clojure url"}})
... <a lot of output, omitted to protect the innocent>...
```

assuming that you want to perform a GET request, that is.

Answer (score 2):

[clj-apache-http](http://github.com/rnewman/clj-apache-http) is pretty useful. With it you can do the following:

```
user=> (require ['com.twinql.clojure.http :as 'http])
nil
user=> (def q (http/encode-query {"q" "clojure url"}))
#'user/q
user=> (def url (str "http://stackoverflow.com/search?" q))
#'user/url
user=> url
"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clojure+url"
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for this in 2021 -  `ring.util.codec/form-encode` does this perfectly:
http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring-codec/ring.util.codec.html#var-form-encode

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution using str(ings):

```
(def q (str "clojure+url"))
(def url (str "http://stackoverflow.com/search?" q))
```

Comment: Well you are giving `+` as an input so you don't actually let Clojure encode the string for you.