# How to convert map to URL query string in Clojure/Compojure/Ring?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

In Clojure / Compojure, how do I convert a map to a URL query string?

```clj
{:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3}
```

to

```
foo=1&bar=2&baz=3
```

Is there any utility method to do this in compojure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure building of URL from constituent parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644125/clojure-building-of-url-from-constituent-parts)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there is a utility for this already that doesn't involve Hiccup or rolling your own string/join/URLEncoder function:

```
user=> (ring.util.codec/form-encode {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
"foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"
user=>
```

Compojure depends on ring/ring-core, which includes ring.util.codec, so you already have it.

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
(defn params->query-string [m]
     (clojure.string/join "&" (for [[k v] m] (str (name k) "=" v))))
```

should do it...

REPL session:

```
user> (defn params->query-string [m]
         (clojure.string/join "&" 
            (for [[k v] m] 
               (str (name k) "="  (java.net.URLEncoder/encode v)))))
#'user/params->query-string
user> (params->query-string {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
"foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"
user>
```

Comment: I might also use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode` on each value in the map, i.e. `(for [[k v] m] (str (name k) "=" (java.net.URLEncoder/encode v)))`.

Comment: I did the same thing, but Is there a utility method to do this?

Comment: @Sathish [Hiccup](http://weavejester.github.com/hiccup/) provides some [relevant functionality](http://weavejester.github.com/hiccup/hiccup.util.html#var-url): `(hiccup.util/url "/hello" {:a 1 :b 2})  => "/hello?a=1&b=2"`.  If you don't want to add a dependency on Hiccup just for a single utility function, writing the function yourself really isn't a big deal.

Comment: i'm sorry, but it is a big deal if the main answer doesn't do it right by omitting the encoding.  people make mistakes; use a library.

Comment: @andrew cooke - agree - I updated my answer with user100464 suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn to-query [inmap]
    (->> inmap
       (map (fn [[f s]] (str (name f) "=" (java.net.URLEncoder/encode (str s) "UTF-8"))))
       (clojure.string/join '&)
       ))
```

This code removes ':' from keywords, but will throw exception if keywords are numbers.

```
(to-query {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
=> "foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"
```